# problrm with array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

this is my Stata.h

```
  #include "State.h"
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

    class State
    {
    public:
        int data[4][4];
        int x;
        int y;
        int cost[];
        State(void);
        void CopyState(State*);
        bool equals(State*);
        int h(State*);
        void print(void);

    private:
        int getLocation(State, int, int);

    };
```

and this is my State.cpp

```
#include "State.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


State::State(void)
{
    State::cost[]  = {0, 3,  2,  5,  3,  4,  1,  2,  2,  1,  4,  3,
                 5, 2,  3,  2,  3,  0,  3,  2,  2,  3,  2,  1,  
                 1, 2,  1,  4,  2,  3,  2,  3,  2,  3,  0,  3, 
                 1, 2,  3,  2,  4,  1,  2,  1,  3,  2,  3,  2,  
                 5, 2,  3  ,0  ,2 , 1 , 4 , 3  ,3 , 4  ,1 , 2,  
                 2, 3,  2,  5,  3,  2,  1,  2,  0,  3,  2,  3,  
                 3,  2, 1  ,2  ,2 , 1  ,4  ,3 , 4  ,3  ,2 , 1 ,
                 3  ,0, 3,  2,  2 , 3,  2,  1 , 1 , 2,  1,  4, 
                 1 , 2, 3  ,4  ,2  ,3  ,0  ,3  ,1 , 2  ,3  ,2 ,
                 4  ,1, 2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  3,  0, 
                 2  ,1, 2 , 3  ,3  ,4  ,1  ,2 , 2 , 1  ,4  ,3, 
                 3 , 2, 1,  2,  0 , 3 , 2 , 3,  3 , 2,  1,  2, 
                 1  ,2, 1 , 4  ,2  ,3  ,2 , 1 , 3 , 0 , 3 , 2,
                 4 , 3, 2 , 1 , 4 , 1,  2 , 1 , 1 , 2,  3 , 2, 
                 2,  3 ,0  ,3  ,1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 3  ,4 , 1  ,2,
                 2  ,1, 2,  3 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 0,  2,  1,  2,  3,
                 5 , 2  ,3 , 2  ,2  ,1 , 4  ,3  ,3  ,4  ,1  ,2, 
                 0  ,3,  2,  5,  2 , 3 , 2,  3,  1,  2,  1,  4,
                 2  ,3  ,2 , 1  ,3 , 0  ,3 , 2,  3 , 2  ,3  ,2 ,
                 4  ,1,  2,  1,  1 , 2,  3 , 2 , 2,  3 , 0,  3, 
                 2  ,3  ,2 , 5 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 1  ,4 , 3 , 
                 5 , 2  ,3  ,0  
               };
}

void State::CopyState(State *state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                data[i][j] = state->data[i][j];
        x = state->x;
        y = state->y;
}

bool State::equals(State *state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
              if (data[i][j] != state->data[i][j])
                return false;
    return true;
}

int State::h(State *state)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            int frmPos = 4 * i + j;
            int toPos = getLocation(*state, i, j);
            k += cost[16 * frmPos + toPos];
        }
    return k;
}

void State::print()
{
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << data[i][j];

    }
    cout << endl;    
}
```

the problem is in State.cpp in the constructor when I'm trying to assign values to the cost array I don't know where is the problem, please any one can solve that , sorry for my bad english

Comment: **Never** put a using directive in a header. Anyway, `cost` isn't an array, it's a pointer. You can't assign to arrays anyway. You'd be better off using a proper abstraction and a function that returns that data imo.

Comment: Right now your bigger problems are (a) you're language syntax isn't correct, and (b) even if it was, all your `State` objects will share the *same* array, which is almost assuredly *not* what you're trying to accomplish. if it is, it should be a const class *static* member and initialed in global scope.

Comment: And now you've changed `cost` from a pointer to a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it that way.  There's a couple of problems, but the first problem is this:

In the header you declare `cost` as an array with an unspecified size:

```
int cost[];
```

This isn't allowed in Standard C++ because now the compiler doesn't know how big the array is, and therefore doesn't know how big `State` will be. (Some compilers *do* allow it, but it's a special extension that won't work on other compilers.)

The *simplest* and often *best* way to do this is to use a `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
class State
{
  // ...
  std::vector <int> cost;
};
```

And then in the constructor:

```
State::State()
{
  static const int startingValues [] =
    {0, 3,  2,  5,  3,  4,  1,  2,  2,  1,  4,  3, ... };
  static const size_t numStartingValues = sizeof (startingValues) / sizeof (startingValues [0]);

  std::copy (startingValues, startingValues + numStartingValues, std::back_inserter (cost));
}
```

If you're using C++11, then this is made simpler with the uniform initialization syntax:

```
State::State()
:
  cost {0, 3, 2, 5, ...}
{
}
```

Comment: @BassamBadr That's the same in every C++ implementation, the header [`<vector>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Anything prepended with `std::` should be in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `cost` member is not an array, it is a pointer *(or it was when I looked at it, but you've changed it. However, it's still not an array. It is now a compiler error.)*.  If you want it to point to an array, first you have to allocate it.  But that's a terrible idea. Change it to a vector:

```
class State {
...
    std::vector<int> cost;
...
};
```

Then, in your constructor, you can initialize it like this (if your compiler supports C++11)

```
State::State() :
    cost{0, 3,  2,  5,  3,  4} // trimmed for brevity, but you can put as many elements as you want
{}
```

If your compiler does not support C++11 (or does not support this feature), then you can initialize the vector like this:

```
State::State()
{
    static int temp[] = {0, 3,  2,  5,  3,  4};
    cost.assign(temp, temp + sizeof(temp) / sizeof(*temp));
}
```